# CakePHP: views are blank b/c of wrong caching config

Tags: cakephp, caching

I experienced very strange behaviour with a CakePHP site in production. Some views did not show up, responding with an HTTP code 200 but without any payload. The browser's screen was blank gray.

I tracked it down to caching. Deleting the *tmp/cache* folder helped the first time, but not today.

So I turned of caching completly by using

```
Configure::write('Cache.disable', true);
```

in *config/core.php* . That fixed the issue and *tmp/cache* folder stayed empty, but the site is slower.

To improve performance I read a little more documentation about CakePHP and found that I must have misunderstood a lot of things about cache configuration.

This is what I used to do in *config/core.php* and **does not seem to be right:**

```
//Configure::write('Cache.disable', true);
//Configure::write('Cache.check', true);
Cache::config('default', array('engine' => 'File'));
```

I didn't include the *Cache helper* in any model or controller.

So I understand that my first approach was not correct, but turning off caching completly is too slow. The minimum I want to cache are my models so I don't need to query the DB for them and maybe cache some views.

What should I do and what is the correct configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good article how to speed up CakePHP http://www.pseudocoder.com/archives/8-ways-to-speed-up-cakephp-apps

The correct cache configuration examples are [here](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1515/Cache-config)